# How can I sort and separate this Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

How can I sort this Collection by the values? It is needed also to add another index before each item because this way it is not possible since two items will have the same index, in our case: "User1".

I need this Collection:

```
Collection {#254 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "User1" => Collection {#253 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        3 => 12.0
      ]
    }
    "User2" => Collection {#255 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        3 => 11.0
        1 => 13.0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to be sorted by the last values, and be separated in other "items":

```
Collection {#254 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "User2" => Collection {#255 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        1 => 13.0
      ]
    }
    "User1" => Collection {#253 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        3 => 12.0
      ]
    }
    "User2" => Collection {#255 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        3 => 11.0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can convert it in an array and make an iteration, but maybe Laravel has a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `sortBy()` method. And specify wich value you want to sort

Here you can find all information you need about the collection methods:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sort